# It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope

Tags: pine-script

line 111: The function 'sma' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope.

```
v7  = 0.0
v7 := na(v7[1]) ? sma(src, len) : (v7[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len    // Smoothed
```

// here error on

// if someone know about this ..please solve above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken sma out of ternary operator.
Please try below code

```
v7  = 0.0
smacopy=sma(src, len)
v7 := na(v7[1]) ? smacopy : (v7[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len    // Smoothed
```